# Show that the derived set of $A$ in a subspace $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$ is equal to $A^d \cap Y$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Set Theory and General Topology" by Fuichi Uchida.

There is the following problem in this book:

> Let $(X, \mathcal{O})$ be a topological space.
> Let $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$ be a subspace of $(X, \mathcal{O})$.
> Let $A \subset Y$.
> Show that the derived set of $A$ in a subspace $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$ is equal to $A^d \cap Y$, where $A^d$ is the derived set of $A$ in $(X, \mathcal{O})$.

My answer is the following:

> The derived set of $A$ in a subspace $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$ is equal to $\{x \in Y \mid x \in \overline{A - \{x\}}\}$.
> $A^d = \{x \in X \mid x \in \overline{A - \{x\}}\}$.
> So, it is obvious that the derived set of $A$ in a subspace $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$ is equal to $A^d \cap Y$.

The author's answer is the following:

> Let $O \subset X$ and $y \in Y$.
> Then $Y \cap O \cap (A-\{y\}) = O \cap (A-\{y\})$ holds.
> For any open set $O$ which contains $y$, if $Y \cap O \cap (A-\{y\}) \neq \emptyset$, then $y$ is an accumulation point of $A$ in $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$.
> For any open set $O$ which contains $y$, if $O \cap (A-\{y\}) \neq \emptyset$, then $y$ is an accumulation point of $A$ in $(X, \mathcal{O})$.
> So, the derived set of $A$ in a subspace $(Y, \mathcal{O_Y})$ is equal to $A^d \cap Y$.

Is my answer correct or not?

I think the author's answer is not simple.
Why did the author write the above answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not correct because you're using the closure in $X$ and not in $Y$. What you've to show is that the closure of $A$ in $Y$(as a subset of $Y$), which I will denote by $cl_Y(A)$ is equal to $cl_X(A) \cap Y$, where $cl_X(A) $ is the closure of $A$ in $X$. When you write something like "$x \in \overline{A - \{x\}}$" it is not clear what closure you are referring to.

Comment: Pankaj Tiwari, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will show $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A) = \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \cap Y$ for any $A \subset Y \subset X$.
Since $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A)$ is a closed set in $Y \subset X$, there exists $F$ which is closed in $X$ such that $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A) = F \cap Y$.
Then, $A \subset \operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A) \subset F$.
$\operatorname{cl}_{X}(A)$ is the smallest closed set in $X$ which includes $A$.
So, $\operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \subset F$.
So, $\operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \cap Y \subset F \cap Y = \operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A)$.
On the other hand, $\operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \cap Y$ is a closed set in $Y$ and $A \subset \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \cap Y$.
Since $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A)$ is the smallest closed set in $Y$ which includes $A$,  $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A) \subset \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \cap Y$.
So, $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A) = \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A) \cap Y$.

So, $\operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A - \{x\}) = \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A - \{x\}) \cap Y$ for any $x \in X$.

So, $\{x \in Y \mid x \in \operatorname{cl}_{Y}(A - \{x\})\} = \{x \in Y \mid x \in \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A - \{x\}) \cap Y\} = \{x \in Y \mid x \in \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A - \{x\})\} = \{x \in X \mid x \in \operatorname{cl}_{X}(A - \{x\}) \cap Y$